# How to run ODI (Oracle Data integrator) loadplan in java

Tags: java, groovy, oracle-data-integrator

We have scripted all of the processes (creating models, table mapping, screnario and loadplan in java using groovy libraries).

Now we want to execute the create loadplan in java.
Somebody please provide the guidelines to script the execution code in java.
We got the method to execute from command prompt.

But looking for option to script in java.

Answer (score 0):

A load plan or scenario execution can be triggered through the class [RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/runtime/agent/invocation/RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.html) from oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation. Check the `invokeStartLoadPlan` methods.